# Joining two separate curves smoothly using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Joining two separate curves smoothly using geometry nodes

I'm trying to join two separate curves `"smoothly"` using geometry nodes. When the two curves are joined at the endpoint it creates a `"harsh" angle` where they are connected.  How can I smooth this out?

[image: img1]

I tried `Resample Curve` and I tried `Fillet Curve` in different places but the sharp angle still persists.

I'm trying to get something somewhat seamless that will gradually / smoothly go straight up.
Like this.

[image: img2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this seems to work:

Realize Instances, then Convert to Mesh, Merge by Distance (with All selected) and convert back to Curve.

[image]

To answer Robin Betts' question:

No, it isn't necessary, but I think it has a nicer finish. This is the same without the "Set Spline Type" and with both curves set to the same resolution (80).

[image]

Comment: The important bit being: _Set Spline Type_ ?

Comment: I replied to your question and added another screenshot. Please feel free to let me know if there is anything wrong or if anything is missing.

Comment: Thanks!  For once, I didn't check for myself :)    Looks fine!